# can loose coupling be achieved in spring just by using annotations - avoiding xml

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, interface, loose-coupling

I have gone through a example from https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-loosely-coupled-example/ .
The example below uses beans to achieve loose coupling.
How can we achieve the same loose coupling using annotations instead of beans?

```
package com.mkyong.output;
public interface IOutputGenerator
{
    public void generateOutput();
}


package com.mkyong.output.impl;
import com.mkyong.output.IOutputGenerator;
public class CsvOutputGenerator implements IOutputGenerator
{
    public void generateOutput(){
       System.out.println("Csv Output Generator");
    }
}

package com.mkyong.output.impl;
import com.mkyong.output.IOutputGenerator;
public class JsonOutputGenerator implements IOutputGenerator
{
    public void generateOutput(){
        System.out.println("Json Output Generator");
    }
}


package com.mkyong.output;
import com.mkyong.output.IOutputGenerator;
public class OutputHelper
{
    IOutputGenerator outputGenerator;

    public void generateOutput(){
        outputGenerator.generateOutput();
    }

    public void setOutputGenerator(IOutputGenerator outputGenerator){
        this.outputGenerator = outputGenerator;
    }
}
```

Spring-Common.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="OutputHelper" class="com.mkyong.output.OutputHelper">
    <property name="outputGenerator" ref="CsvOutputGenerator" />
</bean>

<bean id="CsvOutputGenerator" 
    class="com.mkyong.output.impl.CsvOutputGenerator" />
<bean id="JsonOutputGenerator" 
    class="com.mkyong.output.impl.JsonOutputGenerator" />
</beans>
```

Main class

```
package com.mkyong.common;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import com.mkyong.output.OutputHelper;

public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext context =
           new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"Spring-
           Common.xml"});

        OutputHelper output = (OutputHelper)context.getBean("OutputHelper");
        output.generateOutput();

    }
}
```

Comment: Read about `@Configuration` and `@Bean` annotation

Comment: The xml version is no more loosely coupled than the programmatic version, the only difference is that the choice is made in xml instead of code. What have you gained?

Comment: The real power with polymorphism comes from the fact that you can have different outputgenerators with the same interface, so that you can write code that is oblivious to the specific type of output generator. But when you need to run the code, you still have to make a choice of which output you want. And this code needs to be explicit, there is no way around it.

Comment: @Jens : Thanks for your suggestion